# Site to site VPN restrictions

Tags: networking, vpn

Just wondering if someone could help me. One of our engineers have requested VPN access to one of our customers networks for remote troubleshooting and support. The customer has sent us Site-to-site VPN request document, My question is; Is there anyway for us to use our current Draytek 2860 for both VPN traffic and normal traffic as we don't really want our entire office to be routed through our customers VPN or do we require a completely separate router?

Thank you,

Comment: Or simply install a VPN client on the support engineers PC to connect only during troubleshooting

Comment: Would that require us to contact the customer or could we just fill out the VPN request document as if it was a Site-to-Site?

Comment: i would say VPN server on customer side: client cert for your engineer, be done with.
but that might be impossible for reasons in the customer decision base.
Unrelated: is the customer ATOS? (just wondering)